# I keep getting an error in my driver class, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong

Tags: java

This is a code for a foundations class that I'm working on currently. I keep getting an error, but I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
package miles;

public class Miles {

    private int miles;
    private int gas;
    public static int mpg;

    public void setMiles(int miles) {

        this.miles = miles;

    }

    public void setGas(int gas){

        this.gas = gas;

    }


    public int getMpg(){
        mpg = miles/gas;
        return mpg;
    }


}
```

```
package miles;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MilesDriver {


    public static void main(String [] args) {


        Miles gas =  new Miles();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Miles: ");
        int setGas = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Gas: ");
        int setMiles = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("MPG:  %n%s%n",  gas.getMpg() );


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your post and include error message so other people with same error will be able to find your question and potential answers to it.

Comment: Hint: where exactly are you setting up/passing values for gas and miles for Miles object? Also take a look at what values you are asking from users and how you named your variables.

Comment: `Miles gas =  new Miles();` that's very bad naming decision buddy... further, you're reading "miles" into "setGas" and gas into "setMiles"...

Answer (score 0):

You actually forgot to set the values of your object :

```
    System.out.println("Enter Miles: ");
    int setMiles = input.nextInt();
    gas.setMiles(setMiles);

    System.out.println("Enter Gas: ");
    int setGas = input.nextInt();
    gas.setGas(setGas);
```

Try not to give a variables name the same name as a method of your object. You'll end confusing yourself and get stuck.